# Strato VM stops connecting via SSH after reboot

Tags: ssh, virtual-machines, failed

I have a virtual machine by strato. After rebooting VM can't access via ssh. Strato has  a Recovery Manager which keeps the recovery sytem under /repair. How should I start to debug the issue which logs should I check?

Answer (score 1):

Could be anything.

- is the ssh daemon starting at boot time?
- check /var/log/* for anything suspicious (grep -r ssh /var/log)
- is ssh using port 22? Check /etc/ssh/sshd_config
- check the firewall configuration whether port 22 is blocked

If all fails, purge then reinstall the ssh package, this should reset everything to the well known defaults.